# Properly compare IntPtr to int

Tags: c#, intptr

What is the proper way to compare an `IntPtr`’s value to an `int`?

```
IntPtr ContainerBaseAdress = ReadmemoryProperply.ReadProcessPointer(Tibia.Handle, ContainerPointer);

if (ContainerBaseAdress.ToInt32() == 51)
{
    //Executable code
}
```

Or

```
IntPtr ContainerBaseAdress = ReadmemoryProperply.ReadProcessPointer(Tibia.Handle, ContainerPointer);

if (ContainerBaseAdress == (IntPtr)51)
{
    //Executable code
}
```

Or

```
IntPtr ContainerBaseAdress = ReadmemoryProperply.ReadProcessPointer(Tibia.Handle, ContainerPointer);

if (ContainerBaseAdress == new IntPtr(51))
{
    //Executable code
}
```

Or basically, what is the proper way to compare the value of an IntPtr with an int.

Comment: I’d say the last one (since it might not be a 32-bit pointer).

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit app, `IntPtr` will be more like a `long`. It probably won't equal *any* `int`. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: You have to decide what you want to happen on 64 bit. We cannot do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which one you want to use depends on the behavior your want. The first will throw an `OverflowException` if the value of `ContainerBaseAdress` does not fit in a 32-bit integer. This is likely to happen if the IntPtr points to some address and is being run on the 64-bit CLR. If throwing an exception is the desired behavior, then go with that.

The 2nd and 3rd are equivalent. The cast just wraps `new`. However these will not throw an exception, they will just evaluate the false. Which of these you choose is a matter of stylistic preference.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I suppose its up to OP to make that decision of the behavior he/she wants - evaluating to false, or throwing an exception.

Comment: I reworded this to have less "opinion" in the answer, and just state the facts of behavioral differences.

Comment: @vcsjones: Thank you sir! Just wanted to get clear if you could compare IntPtr without any drawbacks like The first comparision etc.
Cause all I really want is to compare the value in the IntPtr, and I bet it´s better to work around with IntPtr, and do the comparsion with "converted" ints to IntPtr. Rather then reading memory, converting the IntPtr to an Int. (Since this stage requires marshaling to get the IntPtr to an Int)
Do you think it´s a good approach working with IntPtrs rather than ints?